# Create Array of unknown type via parameter

Tags: java, arrays

People have asked similar questions, but I'm not sure I quite understand the answers or if they apply to my situation.

How do I create an Array of a type that is define in method parameter?

```
public void newArray(Object type){
    type[] theArray = new type[5];
}
```

Obviously, this doesn't work, but it's the functionality I need. Thanks!

Comment: Before us trying to answer, are you sure that your question is not an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) in disguise? You may wish to consider telling us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it.

Comment: You might need a [generic type](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_generics.htm)

Comment: What exactly you are asking for? Java does not allow you to define types in parameters. You can figure out of which exact type the parameter is, but was this the question? You can create an array of Object type as `Object [] theArray = new Object[5];` which might satisfy all your needs.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`Array.newInstance(Class, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance-java.lang.Class-int-) but you will need to pass the `Class` (not the `Object` itself), and use a generic type. Like,

```
public <T> void newArray(Class<T> type){
    T[] theArray = (T[]) Array.newInstance(type, 5);
}
```

Comment: @shmosel True, but the argument type in OP's post was `Object`.

Comment: Seems a bit of stretch to deduce from that that the target component type extends `Object`, but maybe.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can create a function that will take class and list as arguments and return an array:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T[] newArray(Class<T> clazz, List<T> list){
    T[] array = (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, list.size());
    list.toArray(array); // fills array with values from list
    return array;
}
```

2) You can create a function that will return an array for you:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T[] newArray(Class<T> clazz, int size){
    return (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, size);
}
```

This function returns array of proper type so you can use it wherever you need and fill it with objects (it contains nulls).

```
int size = 5;
MyType[] myArray = newArray(MyType.class, size);

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    myArray[i] = new MyType();
}
```

3) You can make a list and than make an array inside your method:

```
List<MyType> list = new ArrayList<MyType>();
MyType[] array = list.toArray(new MyType[list.size()]);
```